# Android .AAB file + PAD cannot be uploaded to Google Play

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, assets, android-asset-delivery

I am building an app using React Native that involves the use of many assets (specifically .mp4 files).
My app is around 430mb.

On the Android side, I have followed the Play Asset Delivery official documentation, and I cannot get it to work.

I am only using install_time assets, and therefore have not used the Play Core API. After setting everything up (as per the documentation), I generate a Signed Bundle, and try to upload it for internal testing on Google Play Console, only to get an error back because of my bundle size being larger than 150mb.

I cannot find anything online about this, as there are no tutorials or helpful documents yet, and everything I have found has been Unity related, which I am not using.

I currently have a module for the install_time_asset_pack, and a AndroidManifest.xml was generated when I built my app. That being said the bundle is still above 150mb and the Play Console does not seem to split the encapsulated .APK file and the PAD when I try to upload.

Does anyone know anything about this? Or can someone point me to an actually helpful tutorial to implement PAD? Preferably not unity related please.

Thanks!

[image]

EDIT:

So it seems the APK generated in my .aab file (the base folder) was larger than 150mb. It seemed to also keep the assets I split into the asset-packs, and thats why it had the large size. So I unzipped the .aab, removed those, and now I don't know how to zip the .aab together again. Any thoughts?